# jquery .html(...) changes unchanged?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make changes inside an `A` tag with `.html()` and later make it a `ui-button`. The changes are ok, but then when I call the `.button` in the link just modified the changes are lost.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDysR/3/)

I think that the problem is that the new inner html is not completely rendered and the `.button` function uses the old inner html to make the changes in the code, restoring it to its value before the `html()` call.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570061/how-can-i-tell-when-changes-to-jquery-html-have-finished) but don't work. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hDysR/4/)

I know I can workaround it, but I would like to know why is this happening, is it a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Problem seems to be with `$('#button').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-folder-open'} });`. Could be a syntax error here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
   $('#button').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-folder-open'} });
   $('#textChanger').click(
    function (){
        $('#button').button({
                              label: 'new text',
                              icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-custom', secondary: null}
                           });
        return false;
    })
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/hDysR/8/) is the working fiddle

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew `.button` has an option to set the inner html. I'll give you the accepted despite you have not answered my original question.. is this a bug in jquery's `.html`? and also do you know if this happens with other methods different than `.button`? thanks again

Answer (score 3):

As you say it looks like a difference between the button objects persistence of the text and the original element content, you can change the caption via `.button` however;

```
 $('#button').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-folder-open'}, label: "new text" });
```

but as the button has already been created better to;

```
 $('#button').button("option", "label", "new text");
```

Comment: I've marked user1008575's answer as accepted because he answered one minute before you.. but thanks a lot, I'm using your code. And also... do you know why this happens? is it a bug?

Comment: The control probably has to track the label independently of the html,   for example if you use an icon then its html is also part of button.html() so overwriting it would break the image

Comment: yes, I understand that the `.html(..)` breaks the button image (and any other code inside the 'A' tag), but the `.button()` call after the `.html(..)` should make the changes to the new code, but it uses the old one, witch must be ¿cached? somewhere... The question is: from where takes the `.button()` the code inside the element to change it? and why `.html()` doesn`t change that code... It seems like as I marked an answer as accepted no more people will come here to throw some light over this theme..

Comment: Updating the html *could* change the button, but that not the way its designed, they don't want you messing with the buttons inner html so they keep the original text, and all subsequent changes to it, in the internal `label` property; http://jsfiddle.net/hDysR/9/